# SlidingTabLayout Tabs not clickable

Tags: android, toolbar, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm implementing sliding tab layout under a toolbar in android and everything is showing on screen and working accept that touching the tabs will not do anything - only swiping will work.

My main need is to actually disable the swiping and use it as plain-old tabs. What am I missing?

I believe I set it up right :

```
   ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPage);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getFragments()));

        SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

And in XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/da_blue" />

<dapulse.dapulse.com.dapulse.app.SlidingTabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"></dapulse.dapulse.com.dapulse.app.SlidingTabLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPage"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this behaviour (clicking on tabs to move to the next tab) is given from the beginning. It didn't work for me until I found out the solution. For some reason they didn't work until I called "bringToFront()" on them. Once I did, they worked like they should!

Comment: The reason why it was not working is probably because you overlapped your SlidingTabLayout with ViewPager (match_parent). Add     `android:layout_below="@id/tabs"` in your ViewPager and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

i made few modificaiton on your code, it should work now:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/barLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/da_blue" />

<dapulse.dapulse.com.dapulse.app.SlidingTabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"></dapulse.dapulse.com.dapulse.app.SlidingTabLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/barLayout"
    android:id="@+id/viewPage"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem.
My app worked on latest devices(6) but not on older devices (4.4.2).

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:id="@+id/notification_viewpager"/>
```

giving weight to the viewpager, and setting the height to 0 worked for me.